# 7 letters you have to answer or else

Tags: riddle, word

I am a 7 letter word when you remove 2 letters I become short what word am I?

Comment: This is a very famous question, but usually written the other way round. It's usually phrased as 'I'm a 5 letter word, add 2 letters and I become shorter'.

Comment: Yeah Beastly Gerbil is right. It's not particularly interesting that a word would become short when you take letters away from it.

Answer (score -4):

I believe the answer is

> 'shorter'

because

> when you remove e and r the word becomes 'short'.